# Not able to give a specific ul a different css style?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to give this part of the HMTL a specific CSS style:

```
<div id = "comp_display1" style = "display: none;">
<div class = "ui-widget-overlay ui-front"></div>

<div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible" role="log" aria-live="assertive" aria-relevant="additions"></div>


<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front col-xs-3 " style= "height: auto !important;
        width: auto !important;
        overflow : scroll;
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;

    left: 20%;

    z-index: 500;

    flex-wrap : wrap;
    border: medium none;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;"

     tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-describedby="signInPopup" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1">


<div>
                <div class="whiteBg">
                    <div class="sortingTabs">
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>

    <div class="col-xs-2">Details</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3" id="name1">Hotel 1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3" id="name2">Hotel 2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3" id="name3">Hotel 3</div>
</div>
<center>
<div class="table-responsive wrapper" id="infos">


<div class="row">
                <ul >
                    <li class="col-xs-1 compare"><img src="./details_files/experience.png" alt=""></li>
                    <li class="col-xs-2" ><strong>Total Experience</strong></li>
                    <li class="col-xs-3" id= "url1">7 Year(s)</li>
                    <li class="col-xs-3">7 Year(s)</li>
                    <li class="col-xs-3">7 Year(s)</li>
                </ul>
</div>          
.
.
.
AND SO ON UNTIL ALL THE DIV'S HAVE CLOSED
```

I  want to give the unorded list a particular style with this CSS:

```
  ul li{ display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 185px;
    border-right: 5px solid #E6E6E6;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #E6E6E6;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #FFF;}
```

I only want this part of the code to change. How should I label the CSS?

Comment: All that inline CSS makes me cry inside. Prepend your CSS statement with a specific selector from an ancestor, such as `#infos`.

Comment: elaborate please ...

Answer (score 3):

I'm unsure whether I understand your question, but I assume you mean you ONLY want to target that particular `ul` without editing the HTML itself and only making changes to the CSS? If so,you can target specific `ul` by specifying it's parent `id`, i.e.:

```css
#infos ul li { 
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 185px;
    border-right: 5px solid #E6E6E6;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #E6E6E6;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: yeah i only want the target ul li to change

Comment: @AshwinRamesh, did this answer help? Please mark answer as correct if it helps you as it will help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Give the row div wrapping the `ul` a specific class, say `list-wrapper` and then define the style like this:

```
.list-wrapper ul li {
   ...
}
```

Comment: That would be my first port of call too, but I believe he wants to only target that one specific ul without editing the HTML.

Comment: @samuidavid From the ... in the html I cannot assume there is no other ul as a child of the #infos div. You're answer is better if the user doesn't want to change the html.